# getting HttpException:400 in log files

Tags: yii2

My Yii2 app is emailing me these errors.

```
2021-08-15 21:23:54
[192.228.155.xxx][-][a217lked49000ii06qtrivbrnl][error][yii\web\HttpException:400]
yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Unable to verify your data
submission. in
/var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:218
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(179):
yii\web\Controller->beforeAction()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534):
yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(104):
yii\base\Module->runAction()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392):
yii\web\Application->handleRequest()
#4 /var/www/html/frontend/web/index.php(64):
yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}
2021-08-15 21:23:54
[192.228.155.xxx][-][a217lked49000ii06qtrivbrnl][info][application]

$_POST = [
    '_csrf'=>
'pejM1w_BV9Xj_HRgo9AsjsNW130aTEzqqx61C1PXFyLuvfWvX7d6oLKMJgzanWfenDi8KSopC66ab9JqIadzDw=='
    'calculatorForm' => [
        'instype' => '1'
        'txtSumInsuredMtr' => '10,001'
        'CCMtr' => '201.3'
        'txtBasicPremiumSub' => ''
        'NCDMtr' => ''
        'txtBasicPremiumTotalMotor' => ''
        'rider' => '1'
        'stampDutyMotor' => ''
    ]
    'ajax' => 'calculatorForm'
```

]

I have no idea why. Line 64 in `index.php` is this

```
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

The post request in the log is a calculator form. it works fine when i test it. Any ideas?

Comment: It is related to CSRF validation. Usually these errors are caused by weird bots, that does not handle cookies correctly.

Comment: @rob006 ah ok, so would it be safe for me to ignore error 400 from being emailed to me then?

Comment: right now i'm ignoring these `'except' => [
                        'yii\web\HttpException:403', 
                        'yii\web\HttpException:404', 
                    ],`